# jooq insert from sql file

Tags: java, spring, mustache, jooq

I have my insert.sql file and over 10 rows inside with command `INSERT INTO`

And I try to insert it using jooq

```
String insertSql = mustacheEngine.getMustacheSource("insert.sql");
dslContext.execute(insertSql);
```

But I get this error

```
Cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement
```

How can I fix it? I use real database and connection

Comment: What SQL dialect are you using?

Comment: i use vertica dialect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vertica doesn't support multiple statements in a prepared statement, and jOOQ by default always creates a JDBC `PreparedStatement` behind the scenes, see: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/statement-type/

However, you can tell jOOQ to use static statements instead (JDBC `Statement`), [which should support multiple statements in Vertica](https://forum.vertica.com/discussion/239843/vertica-throwing-exception-for-multiple-sql-statement-support).

```java
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connection, SQLDialect.VERTICA,
  new Settings().withStatementType(StatementType.STATIC_STATEMENT));
ctx.execute(insertSql);
```